Motherboard post failture, strange beep code (gigabyte ga-p35c-ds3r)
So I have this motherboard that I was planning to build a server on, but it won't post. There is a beep code: three beeps, then pause, then 8 beeps, then it instantly reboots. Voltages on the PSU appears to be fine. The CPU and socket are fine,. I tried different RAMs and GPUs, but it doesn't change anything.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

3 beeps, pause, 8 beeps probably indicates a CPU compatibility issue. See from 2007: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/solved-gigabyte-ga-p35-ds3p-beep-codes.420737/ BTW describing a symptom as "strange" is not helpful at all.  "Strange" simply means that you (and not necessarily others) are unfamiliar with it.

@sawdust I've checked, and the CPU is compatible with the motherboard

3 beeps indicate an issue with ram, try use only one in all slots, and 8 beeps If its American Megatrends BIOS, means an issue with VRAM try to plug graphics card in another compatible pc.

I don't think it ram or GPU. As I'm already said I'm tried a lot of different rams and GPUs. Unless it's like PCIe lane on the mb.
